# How long android battery is in discharging mode

Tags: android, battery

I need to know how long my android phone is in discharging mode.For this what i am doing now is- using broadcast receiver to listen when phone is unplugged from charging.Then saving this time in memory.Whenever i need to know the discharging mode period i am finding the difference between current time and the time i have stored previously.

I want to know is there any other way to find this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Recieve the ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED and ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED intent:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED

And just store the time of the disconnected event.

Comment: I mentioned in my question how i did it and wanted to know if something better.What you told is just similar to the work i did.

Comment: You could register for the battery changed intent instead. But that'd be less efficient. Why do you want to do this in another way? Getting the time since the "unplug" is, as far as I know, the most efficient and simple way to do this.

Comment: Of course I registered broadcast receiver for battery changed intent.and from that i know the start time of unplugging.

Comment: But why do you want to do it in another way? :) The most efficient way should be to subscribe for the two intents I suggested (more efficient than the battery changed event).